# Sharepoint list related to another sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint, relationship

Is it possible to attach details from one sharepoint list to another like vlookup in excel? For example if I type unique index in one field, all details will be import from another sharepoint list. Any ideas how to do that? Can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookup column in the SharePoint list.

Reference: [How to create a Lookup column in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-lookup-column-in-sharepoint/#:%7E:text=SharePoint%20Create%20Lookup%20Column%201%20Build%20the%20custom,4%20One%20to%20Many%20Lookups%20%28Optional%29%20See%20More.)

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint lists are not linkable like tables in relative databases. You could write a webpart or script or something else to 'connect' them.
You can use the APIs to get their contents and write a function which processes the contents. After processing you could use another API to write the results in another SharePoint List.

- GET List_1 Data
- GET List_2 Data
- Process(List_1_data, List_2_data)
- POST result to List_n